# how to get tag from CustomURLConnection?

Tags: objective-c, tags, nsdictionary, nsdata

I'm using this code snippet http://snipplr.com/view/43115/ and I wonder how I can access the tag property to do different things with the data in connectionDidFinishLoading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the method's parameter is of type URLConnection, not CustomURLConnection. If you know that the object is in fact a CustomURLConnection, you can re-cast it and extract the "tag" property:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    CustomURLConnection *myconn = (CustomURLConnection *)connection;
    NSLog(@"%@", myconn.tag);

    NSMutableData *dataForConnection = [self dataForConnection:(CustomURLConnection*)connection];
    [connection release];

    // Do something with the dataForConnection.
}
```